# strip all all of numerics with length less or greater than 6

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Hello all and have a lovely day. I want to ask silly question because i am struggling to find the correct pattern. I want to find all numeric characters which are less or greater than length 6.

Let's take a look below. For instance i have this sequence

```
12134 4aRt32212121a 11111111111 222222 asda383652re5
```

My solution is this

```
\b[0-9]{1,5}\b|\b[0-9]{7,20}\b
```

What i got as  matched is this

```
12134 11111111111
```

My problem is that my regex not match any numeric from here 4aRt32212121a. My  desired match will be this one

```
 12134 4 32212121 11111111111 5
```

The numbers will be excluded from match will be 222222,383652 because of the length number equal to 6

i used this [Regex online tool](https://www.regextester.com/) to made my tests. you can make the example here if possible.i would appreciate a lot any kind of help and again forgive me for my stupidness

Comment: What is the tool/programming language you are using? Are you *extracting* to obtain a list of matches, or are you going to replace any of these?

Comment: Would 4aRt32212121a also match '4' ?

Comment: @sniperd `4` is in the desired output

Comment: @sniperd 4aRt32212121 will be match 4 yes i have it the desired ouptu

Comment: ha thanks, caffeine has not kicked in yet :)

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew can you post the duplicate question in your comments i am so curious to see it thnx.

Comment: No need to, the link is below your question heading

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew you are right my mistake then i didnt search for python regex can i delete the question?

Comment: There is no need to delete the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Eily mentioned in other comment the first issue is \b. This is an anchor for word boundary so it will not match the numbers that are in words like you suggested.

My solution is to remove \b and to make sure you don't get any weirdness add negative lookahead and negative lookbehind and the end and start of your search.

`(?<!\d)(\d{1,5}|\d{7,})(?!\d)`

edit: accidently typed {1,6} instead of {1,5}

Comment: Change `6` to `5`

Comment: @MixalisNavridis I think you need a certain level of 'rep' on the site to vote.  But you should be able to accept the answer (the check mark)

Comment: can y make it work with java because some speacial chars gives me Exception

Comment: @JacjPRead i made it working but it is your idea so i cant post it as answer if y have time make more detailed solution for others that might want help s=s.replaceAll(Pattern.compile("(?<!\\d)(\\d{1,5}|\\d{7,})(?!\\d)").pattern(), "");

Answer (score 1):

`\b` means word boundary, ie any place that is not between two `\w` characters, where `\w` means numbers, letter or _. In 4aRt32212121a the 3 comes after a letter, so `\b\d` can't match it. Just remove all your `\b`.

Edited: And since you don't want to match the 5 digit number inside 111111 you need boundary conditions. With look around assertions you can use:

```
(?<!\d)(?:[0-9]{1,5}|[0-9]{7,20})(?!\d)
```

Otherwise (the debugger you have linked to doesn't support them) you have to include either a line boundary or character in the match:

```
(?:^|[^\d])(?:[0-9]{1,5}|[0-9]{7,20}) (?:$|[^\d])
```

Comment: When removing the `\b`, won't it match e.g. a five-digit number that's part of a six-digit number? (Not my downvote, I think you found the problem, but the solution does not suffice)

Comment: Yes, I thought about it right after posting. I'll edit my post, thanks